# Combining 2 data sets with the same columns, but different values

Tags: sql, join, union

I have 2 datasets: Table1 and Table2

Table1 looks like this:

```
Individual_ID    Code1    Code 2  
1234             1        2  
2345             NULL     NULL
```

Table2 looks like this:

```
Individual_ID    Code1    Code 2  
1234             NULL     NULL   
2345             1        2
```

I want the merged result to look like this:

```
Individual_ID    Code1    Code 2  
1234             1        2  
2345             1        2
```

Basically what I am trying to do is bring together multiple tables that have the the same list of IDs and the same Column headers, but the data in the columns associated with the IDs is different in each of the tables I am trying to bring together

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT Individual_ID, Code1, Code2  
FROM table t1
WHERE Code1 IS NOT NULL AND Code2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Individual_ID, Code1, Code2  
FROM table t2
WHERE Code1 IS NOT NULL AND Code2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is great, is there a way to have it return an instance where one of those values happens to be null?
For example:
Maybe table1 has individual_ID with value null and 2 and Table2 has the same individual_id with Null and null. The value I would want in the final table would be Individual_id null and 2
make sense?

Comment: @Ciccotelli412. . . That is what the query does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select t1.Individual_ID, coalesce(t1.code1, t2.code1) as code1,
       coalesce(t1.code2, t2.code2) as code2
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.Individual_ID = t2.Individual_ID;
```

Comment: awesome! Is there a way to do this with a total of 5 tables? same exact scenario

Comment: Just continue the pattern . . . more `join`s, more arguments to `coalesce()`.  If you need additional guidance, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `coalesce`

```
select t1.Individual_ID, 
       coalesce(t1.code1,t2.code1) as code1, 
       coalesce(t1.code2,t2.code2) as code2
  from table1 t1 
  join table2 t2 on t1.Individual_ID = t2.Individual_ID
```

Edit: You can do it for five tables with the same scenario as

```
select t1.Individual_ID, 
       coalesce(t1.code1,t2.code1,t3.code1,t4.code1,t5.code1) as code1, 
       coalesce(t1.code2,t2.code2,t3.code2,t4.code2,t5.code2) as code2
  from table1 t1 
  join table2 t2 on t1.Individual_ID = t2.Individual_ID
  join table3 t3 on t1.Individual_ID = t3.Individual_ID
  join table4 t4 on t1.Individual_ID = t4.Individual_ID
  join table5 t5 on t1.Individual_ID = t5.Individual_ID
```

Comment: You need to qualify Individual_ID in the select list.

Comment: @barbaros is there a way to do this with 5 different tables? same exact scenario, there are just 5 tables that i am trying to bring together

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan now how would I do it if the individual_ids were unique to each table? same column names, but none of the lists have the same individual_id present